# Error " no known conversion from 'std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >' to 'double *' " when using std::count_if()?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm using `std::count_if()` to iterate over each "column" of a vector of vectors, and return the # of items both greater than some value, and within a certain 'range of rows'. For some reason, I'm getting the erorr:

`note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >' to 'double *' for 1st argument`

Referring to the first argument, `coln`, of the lambda.

My code (where `TO` and `FROM` are some integer, and `ROWS` is the # of 'rows' in the vector of vectors), which is a within method of a class:

```
vector<vector<double> > channels;            

// Code to ill 'channels' with some data

for(int coln = 0; coln < _chnl; ++coln){
    
 auto start  = std::next(channels.begin(), FROM);
 auto stop   = std::prev(channels.end(), (ROWS-1) - TO);

  return std::count_if(start, stop, [coln, threshold](double row[]){
  return row[coln] > threshold;
  });

}
```

Also note that I'm using the Cling interpreter, however I was able to reproduce the error in Clang as well.

Comment: Once again, can you please stop spamming the same question, [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749701/using-stdcount-if-over-a-single-column-of-a-vector-of-vectors) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749437/no-known-conversion-from-stdvectordouble-stdallocatordouble-to-int) again?

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda is wrong, it should be:

```
[coln, threshold](const std::vector<double>& row){ return row[coln] > threshold;}
```